# posso usar o mesmo Id que eu defini para o Name em HTML?

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5

Para poder manipular as tags html em php eu preciso definir um name para elas, enquanto o javascript utiliza o id, mas eu posso ter algum tipo de problema futuro se eu utilizar o mesmo nome que eu defini para name nos ids?
Ex..`<input type="text" id="user" name="user">`
caso não, essa pratica é recomendada ou utilizada?, ou por convenção geralmente se atribui nomes diferentes?

Comment: Não há problema. Porém lembre-se que o `id` apenas pode ser usado uma vez, não podendo usar o mesmo valor novamente, enquanto o `name` pode ser usado várias vezes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, você pode utilizar o mesmo valor para o atributo `id` e `name` no mesmo elemento sem problemas.

Vale lembrar que o valor do `id` deve ser único para cada documento, já o valor do `name` pode ocorrer mais de uma vez por documento.

> [...] enquanto o javascript utiliza o id [...]

Só uma observação: Você pode selecionar, por javascript, elementos por `id` ([getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)) ou por `name` ([getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)):

```js
 console.log("Elemento por ID:", document.getElementById("user"));
 console.log("Elemento por Name:", document.getElementsByName("user")[0]);
```

```html
  <input type="text" id="user" name="user">
```