# Como faço para que uma função em javascript funcione para uma série dos mesmos componentes individualmente?

Tags: javascript, html5, funções

Por exemplo: Tenho essa função que verifica se o checkbox está checado, porém ela esta funcionando de forma geral e não individualmente visto que esses componentes se encontram dentro de uma tabela, os componentes são gerados dessa forma:

```
     var table = $('#tableproduct').DataTable();

                    results.Nfe.Produtos.forEach(function (element) {

                        var rowNode = table
                            .row.add(['<input type="checkbox" name="check" onChange="verificarCheckBox() " />',
                                element.Codigo,
                                element.Descricao,
                                '<input type="number" class="form-control " style="text-align:right; margin: 3px;" value=' + element.ValorUnitario + '  id="valor" onChange="calcular()" readonly /> ',
                                '<input type="number" class="form-control" style="text-align:right; margin: 3px;" value= ' + element.Qtd + '  id = "quantidade" readonly onChange="calcular() "/>',
                                '<input type="number" class="form-control " style="text-align:right; width: 177px; margin: 3px;"  value="0"   id="quantidade_devolvida"  readonly onChange="calcular(), verificarCheckBox()"/>',
                                '<input type = "number" class= "form-control" style = "text-align:right; margin: 3px;" value="0" id="var_qnt"  onChange="calcular()" readonly />'
                            ])
                            .draw()
                            .node();
```

E a função que verifica o checkbox é essa aqui:

```
 function verificarCheckBox() {
    var check = document.getElementsByName("check");

    for (var i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
        if (check[i].checked == true)
        {
            document.getElementById("quantidade_devolvida").readOnly = false;
            document.getElementById("quantidade_devolvida").style.borderColor = "rgba(60, 141, 188, 0.5)";
            document.getElementById("quantidade_devolvida").style.boxShadow = "rgba(60, 141, 188, 0.77) 0px 0px 6px";
        }
        else if (check[i].checked == false)
        {
            document.getElementById("quantidade_devolvida").value = 0;
            document.getElementById("var_qnt").value = 0;
            document.getElementById("quantidade_devolvida").readOnly = true;
            document.getElementById("quantidade_devolvida").style.borderColor = "rgba(154, 154, 154, 0.51)";
            document.getElementById("quantidade_devolvida").style.boxShadow = "rgb(253, 250, 250) 0px 0px 6px";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: os elementos estão tudo com o mesmo ID?

Comment: Sim, estão sim.

Comment: Experimente utilizar um id para cada elemento :D

Comment: Então meu amigo, o problema é que essas linhas são geradas automaticamente, não teria como criar os componentes com ids diferentes. Você teria alguma outra alternativa?

Comment: Quando você faz isso: `document.getElementById("quantidade_devolvida").value = 0;`, está referenciando o elemento com o id `quantidade_devolvida`, ou seja, como todos os elementos tem o mesmo ID ele adota esse comportamento.. você teria como postar o html da tabela depois de criada?

Comment: A tabela que é gerada é uma dataTable e as linhas são gerar nessa tabela dinamicamente como é apresentado no primeiro código.

Comment: da uma olhada nesse [pen](https://codepen.io/alvaro-alves/pen/JmBwrr?editors=1011)

Comment: No pen o código esta funcionando perfeitamente, mas quando o coloco em produção na minha aplicação o erro: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined" é apresentado, saberia me auxiliar a consertar esse problema?

Comment: eu precisaria de um exemplo do html gerado da sua tabela após a página ser renderizada

Comment: Na verdade o seu grande problema está na definição de id's múltiplos iguais.. Dê uma olhada nesta [outra pergunta do proprio stackOverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/155857/posso-usar-o-mesmo-id-que-eu-defini-para-o-name-em-html)